# In matter of PDEs, can I use ODE solvers for each step?

Tags: julia, numerical-methods, ode, pde

I have equations like this:

```
wl[n]= w[n] + Δx*v[n]
ϕl[n]= ϕ[n] + Δx*ρ[n] 
ρl[n] = ρ[n] - Δt*fρ(ρ,v,w,n)
vl[n] = v[n] - Δt*fv(ρ,v,w,Δx,n)
```

Simulating these equations:
[image]

Can I use ODE solvers to do it in time, then in space. Or, else, is there a Julia package that can help me to get these equations to be unconditionally stable?

Comment: take a look at https://dedalus-project.org/

Answer (score 0):

Do a semi-discretization in space and then call the ODE solver. This is called the method of lines and is one of the most efficient ways to solve a PDE. Examples of this are shown in [Solving Partial Differential Equations in Julia](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=okGybBmihOE) ([notebook form](https://nextjournal.com/sosiris-de/pde-2018)). There are libraries which will help you do this as well, such as [DiffEqOperators.jl](https://github.com/SciML/DiffEqOperators.jl).